# Combine multiple text files using awk

Tags: awk

I have some minutely stats saved in text files and named as 1min.txt, 2min.txt etc.

```
1min.txt
F1,21
F2,32
F3,22

2min.txt
F2,12
F4,32
```

I would like to combine these files in the following format:

```
combined.txt
Field   1min    2min
F1      21      0
F2      32      12
F3      22      0
F4      0       32
```

Some fields may not exist in some files and 0 will be entered for those fields.

I've tried to do it using awk but couldn't find an easy way. Can someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F, '
!seen[FILENAME]++ { 
    fname[++numFile] = FILENAME 
}
{
    flds[$1]++;
    map[FILENAME,$1] = $2
}
END {
    printf "%-10s", "FIELD";
    for (cnt=1; cnt<=numFile; cnt++) {
        file = fname[cnt];
        sub (/.txt/, "", file);
        printf "%-10s", file; 
    }
    print ""; 
    for (fld in flds) { 
        printf "%-10s", fld; 
        for (cnt=1; cnt<=numFile; cnt++) {
            printf "%-10s", map[fname[cnt],fld]+0
        }
        print "";
    }
}' 1min.txt 2min.txt
```

#### Output:

```
FIELD      1min       2min      
F1         21         0         
F2         32         12        
F3         22         0         
F4         0          32
```

Once you have reviewed the output, you can re-direct the output to another file. You can pass as many files at the end as you want. If you have way too many then you can even use shell glob, for eg: `*.txt`

**Note:** I haven't guaranteed the order of fields since they are not always present in all files.

Here is a pure fun `perl` japh that will do the same:

```
perl -F, -lane'
$f{$ARGV}++; $h{$F[0]}
{$ARGV}=      $F[  1  ]
}{print       join"\t",
"FIELD",      map{s/.[tx]+
//x           ;$_}sort{$a
<=>$b}        keys%f;print
join"\n",    map{$f
=$_;         join
"\t",  $f,map
{$h{$f
}{$_}
//=0}
sort{$a
<=>$b}
keys%f
}sort
keys%h;
' *.txt
```

### Output:

```
FIELD   1min    2min
F1      21      0
F2      32      12
F3      22      0
F4      0       32
```

Comment: Thanks Jaypal. This works perfect and I like it being able to process multiple files. It seems you've used a lot of advanced features of awk which I have never used. The only issue I have now is it seems the column is not ordered by numeric value. It's ordered like below: 0min,10min,11min,12min,13min,14min,15min,16min,17min,18min,19min,1min,20min,21min,22min,23min,24min,25min,26min,27min,28min,29min,2min,30min,31min. Is it possible to order it by numeric value?

Comment: @Allen The problem is with globbing. You are probably using `*` to reference all files in your directory. Use `$(ls * | sort -n)` instead. I added a `perl` variant for fun!

Comment: It worked with $(ls * | sort -n)!. Thank you so much. The perl solution also works fine, I will keep it as a back up.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="\t" }
{ keys[$1]; val[$1,NR==FNR] = $2 }
END {
    print "Field", "1min", "2min"
    for (key in keys) {
        print key, val[key,1]+0, val[key,0]+0
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk 1min.txt 2min.txt
Field   1min    2min
F1      21      0
F2      32      12
F3      22      0
F4      0       32
```

If you care about the output order, tell us what order you're looking for - the order the keys were seen across both files or alphabetical or something else. If it's the order they are seen then that'd be:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="\t" }
!seen[$1]++ { keys[++numKeys] = $1 }
{ val[$1,NR==FNR] = $2 }
END {
    print "Field", "1min", "2min"
    for (k=1; k<=numKeys; k++) {
        key = keys[k]
        print key, val[key,1]+0, val[key,0]+0
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, this solutions works but similar to parreal's solution, it doesn't seem easy to process multiple files.

Comment: I had no idea you wanted to process more than 2 files. Wish you'd made that clear in your question, it's not a hard thing to accommodate when you know it's desired. Anyway, @jaypal's awk solution will work for you so good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Using `join`:

```
join -t , input1 input2 -j 1 -o "0 1.2 2.2" -e 0 -a1 -a2 | column -t -s,
```

*Gives:*

```
F1  21  0
F2  32  12
F3  22  0
F4  0   32
```

To add a header:

```
join -t , input1 input2 -j 1 -o "0 1.2 2.2" -e 0 -a1 -a2 | \
     sed '1iField,1min,2min' | column -t -s,
```

And the result looks like:

```
Field  1min  2min
F1     21    0
F2     32    12
F3     22    0
F4     0     32
```

Comment: Thanks Perreal, this solutions works but it doesn't seem easy to process multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

Awk allows you to explicitly read from files, so you can just put all the logic in a `BEGIN` section if you want.  Here is an example:

```
awk -F, '
  BEGIN {
    while (getline <"1min.txt") {
      field[$1]=1
      a1[$1]=$2
    }
    while (getline <"2min.txt") {
      field[$1]=1
      a2[$1]=$2
    }
    print "Field\t1min\t2min"
    for (x in field) {
      print x"\t"(a1[x]+0)"\t"(a2[x]+0)
    }
  }
'
```

Comment: This can spin off into an infinite loop if it fails to open either input file. Dont use `getline` until you've read and fully understand all the caveats at http://awk.info/?tip/getline.

Comment: Thanks Vaughn, this solutions works but similar to parreal's solution, it doesn't seem easy to process multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

I have written some python code to solve you problem.

```
fh_1 = open("1min.txt", "r")
fh_2 = open("2min.txt", "r")
fh_3 = open("combine.txt", "w")

min_c_1 = {}
min_c_2 = {}

lines_of_text = ["Field   1min    2min\n"]

for l1 in fh_1.readlines():
    data = l1.split(',')
    min_c_1[data[0]] = data[1].rstrip()

for l1 in fh_2.readlines():
    data = l1.split(',')
    min_c_2[data[0]] = data[1].rstrip()

for key in min_c_1.keys():
    if key in min_c_2.keys():
        msg = str(key) + "      " + str(min_c_1[key]) + "      " +  str(min_c_2[key]) + "\n"
        lines_of_text.append(msg)
        del min_c_2[key]
    else:
        msg = str(key) + "      " + str(min_c_1[key]) + "      0" + "\n"
        lines_of_text.append(msg)

for key in min_c_2.keys():
    msg = str(key) + "      0" + "       " + str(min_c_2[key]) + "\n"
    lines_of_text.append(msg)

fh_3.writelines(lines_of_text)

fh_1.close()
fh_2.close()
fh_3.close()
```

Please let me know if it does not help.

Comment: Thanks mate. I was thinking if I can't solve it by using awk, I will probably try it using Python. But it seems @jaypal has provided a working solution.