# Deleting lines matching a pattern from a Unix file

Tags: regex, unix, awk, sed

I have a file containing strings of the following format:

```
05|KEEP|REDEFINES|NO_TYPE|PIC|9.

05|DELETE|REDEFINES|VARIABLE.

05|KEEP2|REDEFINES|VARIABLE2
|PIC|9(5).
```

I want to be able to use something like sed or awk to delete lines containing the word REDEFINES but NOT if the word PIC is also in there or if there is no full stop at the end of a line as this means the string has been split over 2 lines. So out of the 4 lines (3 strings) stated above I would only want to delete 05|DELETE|REDEFINES|VARIABLE.

I thought you might be able to use some kind of negation or lookahead but these don't seem to be available or I can't get them to work

Using awk this deletes anything containing REDEFINES in the String following the pattern in the example above:

```
awk '!/[[:print:]]*\REDEFINES[[:print:]]*\./'
```

Similarly using sed:

```
sed '/[[:print:]]*|REDEFINES[[:print:]]*\./d'
```

I just can't work out how to extend it to do what I need. Is this possible in sed or awk or do I need another tool?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk -v RS= '!/REDEFINES/ || /PIC/' file
05|KEEP|REDEFINES|NO_TYPE|PIC|9.
05|KEEP2|REDEFINES|VARIABLE2
|PIC|9(5).
```

Using `sed` (with older input data):

```
sed -i.bak '/REDEFINES/{/PIC/!d;}' file
05|KEEP|REDEFINES|NO_TYPE|PIC|9.
```

Comment: Very good one. Would you mind explaining how it works? Is `{ /PIC/!d; }` the negation of `{/PIC/d}`? I would've imagined `!` before `/PIC/`, but I see it does not work.

Comment: +1 FWIW I'd definitely go with awk on this one for simplicity, clarity, and portability. I've been using sed almost daily for 30+ years and can't parse that sed statement and certainly couldn't have written it!

Comment: @fedorqui: That is weird `sed` syntax where `!` comes after pattern unlike `awk`. That's why Ed recommends `awk` and I will also go with `awk` unless there is a a need for inline editing.

Comment: IMHO it's a bad idea to sacrifice clarity, simplicity, etc. just for inline editing. `awk 'simple' file > tmp && mv tmp file` is IMHO far better than `sed -i 'complicated' file`. I do know people do it though which is why I twisted the GNU awk guys arms to introduce inline editing in GNU awk 4+ so now `gawk -i inplace 'simple' file` is an option if desired.

Comment: I am also for simplicity and my 1000+ thumbs up to you for getting inline editing in GNU-awk 4+.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. However, having now gone to the end of the 10,000-line file I have found a couple of examples where the string is split over 2 lines as shown in the edit above. In these circumstances I also need to retain the lines containing REDEFINES even though they don't contain the word PIC. Sorry for not getting the question right first time.

Comment: If you turn `awk` some around you get `awk '!/REDEFINES/ || /PIC/'`

Comment: @PinkSalmon: Hmm that makes question very different. Are lines always have pipes like `|PIPE|` and is there always a newline after each line as you show in question?

Comment: @anubhava It does. And I apologise for not forumalting my question correctly in the first place. Yes there are always |PIPES|delimiting the 'fields' within each string and yes there is always a new line after each line. 

To my simple mind, the easiest way of looking at is to only delete lines that match the **String|REDEFINES|String.** format and nothing else.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @anubhava I've tried that but it seems to not delete any lines:

    $ awk -v RS= '!/REDEFINES/ || /PIC/' file
    05|KEEP|REDEFINES|NO_TYPE|PIC|9.
    05|DELETE|REDEFINES|VARIABLE.
    05|KEEP2|REDEFINES|VARIABLE2
    |PIC|9(5).


I appreciate your time and effort on this.

Comment: @EdMorton If you get a chance, can you please enforce .. err cajole them to introduce `sed's` `$` like syntax for end of file in `awk`. Pleaseee .. pretty please! `:)`

Comment: @PinkSalmon: I have attached awk's output in answer above. Is that not what you expect?

Comment: @jaypal there's a lot of things I'd love to see introduced to awk too but that's the problem - when you start introducing language constructs for things that are simple to work around you end up with language bloat like some other tool that shall go nameless and then before you know it people are writing brief but totally illegible scripts. The awk approach is to only introduce language constructs for things that are very difficult+lengthy or impossible to do robustly otherwise within the tool and I think that's the right approach. In the case of `$` there's `ENDFILE` and a saved var.

Comment: @anubhava The out put you've shown is exactly what I'm looking for but when I run it I get all 4 lines output.

Comment: Hmm if I am getting this output then probably your awk is too old. Can you check awk version by typing: `awk --version`

Comment: @anubhava Sounds like it. That command won't even run! I've run what /usr/bin/awk and get

/usr/bin/awk:
         main.c $Date: 2009/02/17 15:25:17 $Revision: r11.31/1 PATCH_11.31 (PHCO_36132)
         run.c $Date: 2009/02/17 15:25:20 $Revision: r11.31/1 PATCH_11.31 (PHCO_36132)
         $Revision: @(#) awk R11.31_BL2010_0503_1 PATCH_11.31 PHCO_40052 

It's an HP box and I've noticed that lots of the examples I've seen for sed don't work so perhaps this is all down to HP's implementation....

Comment: Ok I will try to suggest an awk command compatible with older HP awk.

Comment: @PinkSalmon: Can you try: `awk '!d && /REDEFINES/{d=1; p=""} d {if (p) p = p ORS $0; else p=$0} d && ($0=="" || /PIC/){if ($0=="") p=""; print p; p=""; d=0; next}' file` command?

Comment: @EdMorton True, actually I was on my phone that time and didn't convey my comment clearly (apologies for that). The `$` was actually meant to ask about a feature in `awk` where we would know the last line number. Having a variable that would hold the number of lines would reduce a lot of hacky workarounds. `:)` (I think I know which [tool](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25299223/970195) you are talking about. The second solution ... `:P`)

Comment: @jaypal - I fully understood what you were suggesting and my response was about that. I had a discussion about that same thing a few weeks ago on comp.lang.awk with the GNU awk guys and they set me straight (see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.awk/83ltFP2c0gg/lQyDVBKYSssJ) :-). And yes, that'd be the tool (http://www.zoitz.com/archives/13).

Comment: @EdMorton Wow you sure were persistent. Thanks for sharing that.

Comment: @jaypal Yeah, only persistence or cash gets results and I like my gawk free :-). We did uncover and fix a bug related to gawk handling getline incorrectly in ENDFILE so that was good.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below command. Print the line if it contains PIC or if it does not contain REDEFINES. It is maintainable as it is not so tricky and could be understood without much of an effort.

```
cat input.txt | awk '{if ($0 ~ /PIC/ || $0 !~ /REDEFINES/){print $0}}'
```

Comment: You should not use `cat` with programs that can read data itself. And this can be shorten to `awk '/PIC/ || !/REDEFINES/' input.txt`

Comment: Point taken! But the focus here was solely on the awk side.

Comment: The shortened version from @Jotne is even better.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `grep`? Using negations on your question, here is what I understood:

> keep the lines terminated with a full-stop, containing both REDEFINES and PIC.

So grep seems easy:

```
$ grep -E 'REDEFINES.*\.$' file | grep PIC
05|KEEP|REDEFINES|NO_TYPE|PIC|9.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/REDEFINES/{/PIC|[^.]$/!d}' file
```

or perhaps more easily:

```
sed '/PIC/b;/REDEFINES.*\.$/d' file
```

or if you prefer:

```
sed '/PIC/!{/REDEFINES.*\.$/d}' file
```